# HTML Gifs with static size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm writing a responsive website using HTML/CSS and Bootstrap. "Carrousel" is a list of gifs on the website main page. I struggle to find a way to make those gifs static, so that they don't resize when page resizes or you look at it from a mobile.
Ideally I would like them to stay fixed size so that when resizing a page in browser they remain the same size.

```
<div class="row no-gutters m-0 pt-0 Carrousel">
   <ul id="C1">
      <li><img src="assets/gif1.gif" alt="gif-trailer"  width="360" /></a></li>
      <!-- more gifs -->          
      <li></li>  
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Carrousel {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 33vh;
}
.Carrousel ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.Carrousel ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22.5vh;
    width: 17.5vw;
    background-color:#14222C;
    border-radius: 6%;
    margin-right: .5vw;

    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by changing dimensions in `.Carrousel ul li` to pixels instead of the relative vh and vw units.

For example

```
.Carrousel ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px; /* adjust as needed */
    width: 200px;  /* adjust as needed */
    background-color:#14222C;
    border-radius: 5px;  /* adjust as needed */
    margin-right: 5px;  /* adjust as needed */
    padding:0;
}
```

You might need to make similar changes to the CSS for `.Carrousel ul` and for sure you need to do something to `.Carrousel`

The trick will be to find pixel units that work for all devices.